# Duplication Issue (Django Project) - ON FIREFOX ONLY

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a duplication issue, it's happen on Firefox browser only, not on Chrome nor on Safari.

When a user post a post, it's created twice, twice in the database.

I am wondering why this happing on Firefox only?

I cannot debug it or provide you with any codes as this is happing in one browser only.

This code is helpful but not for Firefox:

```
$('.prevent_multiple').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

Comment: Try to use pure Js to see if it can be a jQuery issue.

Comment: Can you write the pure code please?